# Cinema questions about games

Tags: discussion

Not that I'm interested in asking anything about a game right now, but I recently heard that [a video game became eligible to receive an Oscar](http://www.ign.com/articles/2017/06/08/a-video-game-trailer-just-became-eligible-to-win-an-oscar-for-the-first-time). It just made me wonder if this community would eventually open up to receive questions about games that almost work as a movie. In fact there are a few games that feel more like a movie with multiple endings than a game. The first one that comes to my mind is [Heavy Rain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_Rain).

Yes, I know that there is a [Stack Exchange site dedicated to games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) and all. I'm just curious if a question that would involve cinematographic doubts about such a game would be well received. Again, I have no question in mind right now, its just a curiosity.

Just bear in mind that games have many processes in common with movies and there are things called Interactive Movies, which are very much similar with these new Movie Genre Games. So I would think that direction or character development questions would be accepted. So, what do you think?

This is the trailer:

> In a formal statement, the jury stated that the Everything short goes beyond entertainment and has "a strong poetic and philosophical theme.
>
> "It serves a highly educational purpose, including an important political statement, that encourages [us] to let our egos dissolve and gain a new perspective on the world."

-From IGN

Comment: The article you pointed to says that it was a video game *trailer* that was nominated, not the video game itself.

Comment: @Thunderforge Yes. It was already discussed in Paulie_D's answer. But my question was about a little more than that.

Answer (score 10):

I would say...

## NO

It's not a Movie or a TV show.

It may have cinema **quality** footage or cut scenes but that doesn't bring it on-topic.

That said...this is related to a **trailer**

> 11-minute trailer for simulator *Everything* had qualified in the category for best animated short film.
>
> (from your link)

So the **trailer** would be on topic...but not the game itself.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it makes. Its just a curiosity because I do think that some games will be in the future very similar to movies and might really be in the Oscars. Heavy Rain, as I mentioned its really much more of a movie than a game, you do very little compared to what you watch. But alright, I do understand, I just wanted to know how flexible the community is.

Comment: This just my opinion...other may differ and they are free to give their reasons accordingly.

Comment: I will go with No too.

Comment: Just a question: Would the trailer still be on topic if it wasn't eligible to the Oscars?

Comment: @LeonFreire trailer's are typically off-topic for the site because they usually only contain partial information and we'd rather wait for the movie/show to come out as a lot of questions will be answered then.  I haven't seen this particular trailer though to give a full response on whether this one in particular could be on-topic.

Comment: @DForck42 Hmmm... Ok. I just wanted to understand where is the line because a lot of game trailers that are not a gameplay trailer are just stunning cinematics. Are questions about them on-topic? Lets say, if I had a question about this [Star Wars: Old Republic trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nzq9epS2b1A) (Again, I don't have), would it be on-topic? It has little to no difference between a game trailer and a trailer for a Star Wars animation, and it does contain a lot of information.

Comment: If it's publicly available such as on YouTube then I don't see why not. It's not the Oscar here that is important as much as the type of presentation. Web series and short films are on-topic.

Comment: @Paulie_D Ok. So basically, in your opinion, if the user/viewer has any control and is not a cinematic, its a no-go?

Comment: No. It's not about control. In game footage or effects would be off-topic. This is basically a high quality advert and those are on-topic provided were not being asked to ID them.